# Navigation property doesn't exit

Tags: c#, entity-framework, code-first

I'm developing an Entity Framework 6.1.2 Code First library with C# and .NET Framework 4.5.1.

I get this error:

> A specified Include path is not valid. The EntityType
>   'MyProject.Data.SqlServer.Concrete.AGGREGATION_CHILDS' does not
>   declare a navigation property with the name 'Code'.

Note that `MyProject.Data.SqlServer.Concrete` namespace is incorrect. I have `DbContext` declared in `MyProject.Data.SqlServer.Concrete` namespace.

This is `AGGREGATION_CHILDS`class declaration:

```
namespace MyProject.Data
{
    public class AGGREGATION_CHILDS
    {
        public string CODE { get; set; }
        public string PARENT_CODE { get; set; }
        public int POSITION { get; set; }

        public virtual AGGREGATIONS Aggregation { get; set; }
        public virtual CODES Code { get; set; }
    }
}
```

And `CODES` class:

```
namespace MyProject.Data
{
    public class CODES
    {
        public string CODE { get; set; }
        public byte CODE_LEVEL { get; set; }
        [ ... ]

        public virtual AGGREGATION_CHILDS AggregationChild { get; set; }
    }
}
```

And their configuration files:

```
namespace MyProject.Data.SqlServer.Configurations
{
    class AGGREGATION_CHILDSConfiguration : EntityTypeConfiguration<AGGREGATION_CHILDS>
    {
        public AGGREGATION_CHILDSConfiguration()
        {
            HasKey(ag_ch => ag_ch.CODE);

            Property(ag_ch => ag_ch.CODE)
                .HasDatabaseGeneratedOption(DatabaseGeneratedOption.None);

            Property(ag_ch => ag_ch.CODE)
                .HasMaxLength(20)
                .IsRequired();

            Property(ag_ch => ag_ch.PARENT_CODE)
                .HasMaxLength(20)
                .IsRequired();

            HasRequired(ag_ch => ag_ch.Aggregation)
                .WithMany(ag => ag.AggregationChilds)
                .HasForeignKey(ag_ch => ag_ch.PARENT_CODE);

            HasRequired(ag_ch => ag_ch.Code)
                .WithOptional(c => c.AggregationChild)
                .WillCascadeOnDelete(false);
        }
    }
}
```

And the other configuration file:

```
namespace MyProject.Data.SqlServer.Configurations
{
    class CODESConfiguration : EntityTypeConfiguration<CODES>
    {
        public CODESConfiguration()
        {
            HasKey(c => c.CODE);

            Property(c => c.CODE)
                .HasDatabaseGeneratedOption(DatabaseGeneratedOption.None);

            Property(c => c.CODE)
                .HasMaxLength(20)
                .IsRequired();

            [ ... ]
        }
    }
}
```

And this is where I get that error:

```
List<AGGREGATION_CHILDS> agChilds =
                m_AggChildRepo
                .SearchForWithInclude(agCH => agCH.PARENT_CODE == aggregation.PARENT_CODE, "Code")
                .ToList<AGGREGATION_CHILDS>();
```

`SearchForWithInclude` implementation is:

```
public IQueryable<TEntity> SearchForWithInclude(
    Expression<Func<TEntity, bool>> predicate,
    string includePath)
{
    return _dbSet.Where(predicate).Include(includePath);
}
```

`CODES` and `AGGREGATION_CHILDS` have a One-to–Zero-or-One relationship.

Do you know why is complaining about that Code navigation property doesn't exit? Maybe, I haven't create the zero-or-one-to-one relationship correctly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This how I have solved the problem. I think there is an Ambiguous problem.

```
namespace MyProject.Data
{
    public class AGGREGATION_CHILDS
    {
        public string CHILD_CODE { get; set; }
        public string PARENT_CODE { get; set; }
        public int POSITION { get; set; }

        public virtual AGGREGATIONS Aggregation { get; set; }
        public virtual CODES Code { get; set; }
    }
}
```

I have changed `AGGREGATION_CHILDS.CODE` property with `AGGREGATION_CHILDS.CHILD_CODE`.

```
namespace MyProject.Data.SqlServer.Configurations
{
    class AGGREGATION_CHILDSConfiguration : EntityTypeConfiguration<AGGREGATION_CHILDS>
    {
        public AGGREGATION_CHILDSConfiguration()
        {
            HasKey(ag_ch => ag_ch.CHILD_CODE);

            Property(ag_ch => ag_ch.CHILD_CODE)
                .HasDatabaseGeneratedOption(DatabaseGeneratedOption.None);

            Property(ag_ch => ag_ch.CHILD_CODE)
                .HasMaxLength(20)
                .IsRequired()
                .HasColumnName("CODE");

            Property(ag_ch => ag_ch.PARENT_CODE)
                .HasMaxLength(20)
                .IsRequired();

            HasRequired(ag_ch => ag_ch.Aggregation)
                .WithMany(ag => ag.AggregationChilds)
                .HasForeignKey(ag_ch => ag_ch.PARENT_CODE);

            HasRequired(ag_ch => ag_ch.Code)
                .WithOptional(c => c.AggregationChild)
                .WillCascadeOnDelete(false);
        }
    }
}
```

And set what column name will have on database:

```
Property(ag_ch => ag_ch.CHILD_CODE)
    .HasMaxLength(20)
    .IsRequired()
    .HasColumnName("CODE");
```

Answer (score 0):

The line that triggers the error evaluates to

```
m_AggChildRepo.Where(agCH => agCH.PARENT_CODE == aggregation.PARENT_CODE).Include("Code")
```

What is that include supposed to do? Even if you are using Dynamic Linq, what is "Code" supposed to be? All fragments you posted here use fully capitalized attribute and property names.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I have added an answer telling how I have solved the problem.